# The "not:()" selector isn't working with ".live()" when event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I added `live()` to some mousedowns, my `not:` conditional stopped working.

```
 $("body :not(" + _self.somevar + ")").live('mousedown',
     function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     // some more code
 }
```

When it wasn't `live()` it worked.  Now that I use `live()`, when I mousedown on that item, it fires when it shouldn't.

Anyone know why `not:` is no longer adhered to?

Comment: What is `_self.somevar`?

Comment: _self.somevar is the ID of an element

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead

Comment: You realize that the "_self.somevar" will only be evaluated once, right?

Comment: @user1492442 that expression (the ":not" selector) will only be evaluated when you set up the event handler. If that "somevar" changes later, it'll have absolutely no effect on the event handler setup.

Comment: so, does that mean it will work only "once".. basically, I want my code to always fire off when you mousedown on the body EXCEPT when a particular "ID" Is clicked and that id is passed via _self.somevar

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `.live()` method to `.on()` (to work with new versions of jQuery). So you need apply on the `document` an event of `mousedown` selecting the `body :not(#notAcceptedElement)`. Example:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="notAccept">Not Accept Mousedown</div>
<div id="accept">Accept Mousedown</div>
```

**JS** (jQuery 1.6):

```
$('body :not(#notAccept)').live('mousedown', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target);
    $('#accept').clone().appendTo(document.body);
});
```

**JS** (jQuery edge/1.8):

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'body :not(#notAccept)', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target);
    $('#accept').clone().appendTo(document.body);
});
​
```

Live example: [jsFiddle jQuery-1.6](http://jsfiddle.net/DgXUj/1/), [jsFiddle jQuery-edge](http://jsfiddle.net/DgXUj/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem is - we are using prototype 1.6 with no plans to upgrade any time soon. Is there another fix possible with using "live():?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know only one body tag you can use in a HTML page. In your case its better if you try to attach event for id/class. and syntax will be something like this,

For id of element

```
$("#not:'+ _self.somevar'+").live('mousedown',
 function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 // some more code
}
```

For class of element

```
$(".not:'+ _self.somevar'+").live('mousedown',
 function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 // some more code
}
```